# Fb Ads api How to get Active only FB Campaigns?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I am trying to get the campaigns list from facebook ads api I am using below code

```
        $account = new AdAccount('act_' . $account_id);
        $campaignSets = $account->getCampaigns(array(
            CampaignFields::ID,
            CampaignFields::NAME,
            CampaignFields::START_TIME,
            CampaignFields::STOP_TIME,
            CampaignFields::SPEND_CAP,
            'effective_status'
                ));
```

But I need only the active campaigns list so how can I filter the list by Camapign Status = Active only

Thanks,
Ronak Shah

Answer (score 7):

If you check the method declaration for `AdAccount->getCampaigns`, you will see that it accepts two parameters `$fields` and `$params`. `$fields` for the fields that you want to retrieve, and `$params` as a filter. Example in your case (tested with v2.5):-

```
$account = new AdAccount('act_' . $account_id);

$fields = array(
    CampaignFields::ID,
    CampaignFields::NAME,
    CampaignFields::START_TIME,
    CampaignFields::STOP_TIME,
    CampaignFields::SPEND_CAP,
    'effective_status'
);

$params = array(
    'effective_status' => array(
        Campaign::STATUS_ACTIVE
    ),
);

$campaignSets = $account->getCampaigns($fields, $params);
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Sorry thats not a correct answer If you read my question properly I want to filter the campaigns list by status, is this possible to achieve?

Comment: When I used the above code, my $campaignSets only contains campaign with the effective_status of 'ACTIVE'. I tried with CampaignFields::STATUS but it seems to have been deprecated in v2.5. I think you figured that out as well because you queried for the 'effective_status'. @RonakShah

Comment: Yes its working but one issue I need ACTIVE, PAUSED and DELETED Campaigns and If I use like this 'effective_status' => array(
       'ACTIVE', 'PAUSED', 'DELETED'
    ) then it gives error as "Invalid Params" and If I remove "DELETED" from the array then i works whats the problem there?

Comment: @RonakShah I tried the same thing as you and got the same Exception 'Invalid Parameter' with the 'error_user_title' => 'Cannot Request for Deleted Objects', 'error_user_msg' => 'Requesting for deleted objects is not supported at this endpoint.'. I guess you have to contact FB directly to ask them why this is so if your requirement still requires you to get the deleted campaigns. There does not seem to be a way to 'undelete' the campaigns once deleted as well, so I guess the 'DELETED' status is just a way for FB to mark in their own database as soft-deleted.

Answer (score 4):

I can show you how to achieve this using the raw REST-API (I opted not to use FB's unnecessarily convoluted SDK (Python)).

> https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/act_99999999999999/campaigns?status=["ACTIVE","PAUSED","ARCHIVED","PENDING_REVIEW","DISAPPROVED","PREAPPROVED","PENDING_BILLING_INFO","CAMPAIGN_PAUSED","ARCHIVED","ADSET_PAUSED"]&format=json&method=get&pretty=1&limit=250&fields=field1,field2&time_range={"since": "2017-11-01", "until": "2017-12-05"}&access_token=XXX

The key here is the `status=[]` GET parameter.